# Make domain controller automatically register IP of a replacement domain member

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtual-machines, domain-controller, autoscaling

I have 3 VM servers in a domain. One of them is the domain controller with active directory and DNS installed. Another server is an application server. One of the requirements for that application server is to have automatic replacement of the VM if it goes down. The replacement will be identical in its configuration, except for the IP, as it will be dynamically assigned (that's how AWS auto-scaling works by default. Yes, the VMs are in AWS).

My question is: how can I make sure that the domain controller recognizes the replacement instance as the replacement of the instance that died? Would it do this automatically because the machine name is the same? The IP of a replacement VM will be different from the original, so I gotta make sure that the DC updates its DNS with the new IP for that domain member.

Answer (score 0):

You could do DNS failover or some load balancing apps will do failover.

With DNS failover you have to deal with the downtime before the TTL expires. a load balancer is going to be much quicker and some offer resending the same traffic to the second node when the first one fails, but usually will cost more because it's not just checking and updating DNS but more man in the middle sort of thing.

On Azure you have 'traffic manager' which basically handles this for you instead of needing a 3rd party app - I'm sure there's something comparable on AWS.

How it works with traffic manager is you redirect your site to the trafficmanager and it has it's own DNS which offers low TTL values to mitigate the downtime issue.

The azure load balancer does not allow failover so not sure how that would be on AWS.